# when I use unit(i.e. vp, fp, px) with value in xml file then respective attribute not working ? (HarmonyOS)

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am creating a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK, where I created some attributes for my custom component.
Now the problem is "whenever I am trying to set any value in attribute with unit(i.e. vp, fp, px)" then, Respective attribute is not working.

For ex:

```
ohos:iconMargin="8vp"
ohos:text_size="12fp"
ohos:areaMargin="24px"
```

And in my custom component class I get this attribute value like this

```
attr = attrSet.getAttr(areaMargin);
areaMargin = attr.map(Attr::getIntegerValue).orElse(24);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have to just replace

`getIntegerValue()` with `getDimensionValue()`

for ex:

```
attr = attrSet.getAttr(areaMargin);
areaMargin = attr.map(Attr::getIntegerValue).orElse(24);
```

Replace above code with below code

```
attr = attrSet.getAttr(areaMargin);
areaMargin = attr.map(Attr::getDimensionValue).orElse(24);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following example:

.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DirectionalLayout
    xmlns:ohos="http://schemas.huawei.com/res/ohos"
    xmlns:xxxx="http://schemas.huawei.com/res/ohos-auto"
    ...
    xxxx:iconMargin="8"
```

.java:

```
if (attrSet.getAttr("iconMargin").isPresent()) {
    int iconMargin = AttrHelper.vp2px(attrSet.getAttr("iconMargin").get().getIntegerValue(), context);
}
```

Comment: Yes, If I put any value without any **unit** then it's work properly, but whenever I put value with **unit(i.e. vp, fp, px)** then it's not working.